# Rails has_one association expected Model got String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, cocoon-gem

Having the following associations between 3 models:

**workout.rb**

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :workout_sets, :join_table => :workout_sessions
  belongs_to :warmup, :class_name => :WorkoutStep, :foreign_key => "workout_step_id"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_sets, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :warmup, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**workout_set.rb**

```
class WorkoutSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :workout_steps, :join_table => :sets_steps, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :workouts, :join_table => :workout_sessions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_steps, allow_destroy: true

  has_one :intro_video_usage, class_name: 'VideoUsage::Intro', as: :parent, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :intro_video, through: :intro_video_usage, source: :video

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :intro_video

  has_one :get_ready_video_usage, class_name: 'VideoUsage::GetReady', as: :parent, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :get_ready_video, through: :get_ready_video_usage, source: :video

  has_one :congrats_video_usage, class_name: 'VideoUsage::Congratulations', as: :parent, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :congrats_video, through: :congrats_video_usage, source: :video
end
```

and

**workout_step.rb**

```
class WorkoutStep < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :workout_sets, :join_table => :sets_steps
  has_many :main_video_usage, class_name: 'VideoUsage::Main', as: :parent
  has_many :main_videos, through: :main_video_usage, source: :video
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :main_videos
end
```

And using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to handle nested models creation on the top level model (`Workout`) I'm having troubles building the form for `sets` and `steps` - more concise, when associating a `workout_set` with an `intro_video` (and whitelisting the params) I'm having the following error:

> Video(#70285207226600) expected, got String(#70285080848240)

The `params` object after sending looks like this:

```
"workout"=>{"title"=>"",
 "workout_sets_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false",
 "intro_video"=>"70",
 "title"=>""}}},
 "image"=>"",
 "sound_logo"=>"",
 "intro_video"=>"",
 "commit"=>"Create workout"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know what you intended but looks like your code will try and set intro_video to 70 - that is the cause of your error

Comment: I'm just trying to select a video out of a select and associate the `intro_video` attribute to the `workout_set` object

Comment: So 70 is the id of the video?

Comment: is it possible that rails is trying to create a new Video object?

Comment: Can you show us the form code for the intro-video? Normally if you just use `f.association :intro_video` it should just be correct?

Comment: The fact that `intro_video` is a `has_many :through` might also complicate things, so you probably cannot simply assign `intro_video_id`. Can you explain why the `IntroVideoUsage` is there?

Comment: exactly - that was my conclusion yesterday and decided to simplify the associations a little bit, now instead of having a `has_many :through` I associate the 2 models using `intro_video_usage`, which holds a foreign key to the Video (`video_id`). Had to modify the views but did the trick :). Now the form works like a charm. even tough, However, I'm having troubles with this now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594241/maintain-the-order-of-an-array-in-rails-forms @nathanvda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters are passing a string ("70") to `intro_video=` but association accessors like that expect you to pass an actual instance of the associated class (in this case Video).

You should instead be assigning to `intro_video_id`. The accessor will convert the string to an integer for you.

Comment: Are you suggesting changing the name of the association to `intro_video_id`? Don;t quite understand

Comment: No - only the form input needs to change