# Maintain the order of an array in rails forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have 3 models (Workout, WorkoutSet, WorkoutStep) with the following associations:

- A Workout has many sets
- A WorkoutSet has many WorkoutSep
- And a WorkoutStep has an array of videos (called `video_usage[]`)

Using simple_form and cocoon I made the forms to edit such associations but, at the deepest level (the array of videos of WorkoutStep) by the time I edit a Workout, the order seem not to be constant, being, instead, ordered by (guessing) the last time the attribute has been modified (in this case, modified is changing a property, such as selecting another video).

I want the array of videos to remain constant between edits.

This is how my form looks like:

**`_workout_sets_fields.html.haml`**

```
.nested-fields
  = f.simple_fields_for :main_video_usage do |mv|
    = render 'main_video_usage_fields', f: mv
  .steps{ :style => "margin-left: 680px" }
    = link_to_remove_association 'remove step', f
    = link_to_add_association 'add video', f, :main_video_usage
```

**`_main_video_usage_fields.html.haml`**

```
.nested-fields
  = f.collection_select :video_id, Video.all.order(:title), :id, :title
```

Comment: When you say array, you mean `has_many :video_usages` or an actual array?

Comment: The array is `main_video_usage`, and is an attribute of a WorkoutStep

Comment: Ah ok, no idea how it works with arrays, with associations it is easy to give a specific default order (and imho by default ordered by `id` but not sure about that).

Comment: Those were my thoughts, but each time I edit the order changes, being the first the last I edited (note: **the order only changes when I edit**)

Comment: Not sure if I was clear: Are you using `has_many :main_video_usages` ? How did you declare `main_video_usage(s)` ?

Comment: `has_many :main_video_usage, class_name: 'VideoUsage::Main', as: :parent` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :main_video_usage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give an explicit order, use `id` or `created_at` if you want to keep the order of creation:

```
has_many :main_video_usage, -> { order('id asc') }, class_name: 'VideoUsage::Main', as: :parent
```